# Is it possible to extend from fragmentActivity and at the same time extend ActionBarActivity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, extends

I have an activity which extends `FragmentActivity` (to use the *Android Maps API v2*), but I need to make changes to the `ActionBar`, and I always extends `ActionBarActivity` to make changes such changes.
I know it can not be extended too, but can I extend and edit `FragmentActivity` and `ActionBar`?

```
public class AMapsSi extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity {
    private GoogleMap mapa = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.getWindow().setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_amapssi);
        //actionbar
        ActionBar actionBar = **getSupportActionBar();**-->eclipse error mark
        actionBar.setTitle(vg.getCiudad());

        actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.manu_perfil); 
        Drawable d=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.headeractionbar);
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
```

Answer (score 5):

Just extend android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity as it already extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity

The parental hierarchy of ActionbarActivity can be seen here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html

Comment: "Will work well" is very subjective. It depends what you are doing. You will have all of the methods available to you in FragmentActivity unless they are overwritten by ActionBarActivity (unlikely)

Comment: thanks a lot, you post helped me after an hour of searching the solution